# Degrees of freedom for estimation

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, estimators

In the context of estimators, why is it that in general dividing by the degrees of freedom(instead of the sample size) leads to unbiasedness? I see the value in substituting degrees of freedom for sample size for an unbiased estimator in small samples but I don't get why it works.